# changing major/minor axis interval and color scheme for heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

You can find my data set [here](https://gist.github.com/ecenm/3319394b5b816ce02e8f9293b47e6638#file-tors_sorted-txt).

I am using [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) to plot the heatmap. But open to other choices.

I have trouble getting the color scheme right. I wish to have a black and white scheme. As the current color scheme doesn't clear show the result.

I also wish to display only x and y intervals as (0 , 25 , 50, 100 , 127).
How can I do this.

Below is my try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

data_sorted = pd.read_csv("tors_sorted.txt", sep="\t")
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_xlim(right=128)
minor_ticks = numpy.arange(0, 128, 50) # doesn't seem to work

data_sorted= data_sorted.pivot("dst","src","pdf_num_bytes")
#sns.heatmap(data_sorted,ax=ax)
sns.heatmap(data_sorted,linecolor='black',xticklabels=True,yticklabels=True)
ax.set_title('Sample plot')
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.savefig('heatmap.jpg')
```

This is the image that I get.

[image: heatmap]

thanks.

Comment: You're looking for the argument `cmap` in `heatmap`.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out. Any idea on display interval ?

Comment: Might be a wild guess, but `heatmap` returns an `ax` object. You might try `set_xticks` on that.